# Rust: what is tokio::select macthing

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Good evening. I am trying to build a websockets client in Rust. My main coding experience comes from python so I tried to follow this repo: https://github.com/bedroombuilds/python2rust/tree/main/23_websockets_client/rust/ws_client

I just want to listen to a channel and print to the screen; so the logic from the `tokio::select!` in the snippet is not being used in my implementation. But if I do this:

```rust
        let ws_msg = ws_stream.next();
           {
           match ws_msg {
              Some(msg) => match msg {
    ...
```

It won't compile because it cannot match `ws_msg`:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:145:22
    |
144 |                  match ws_msg {
    |                        ------ this expression has type `Next<'_, WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::TcpStream, tokio_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>>>>`
145 |                      Some(msg) => match msg {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Next`, found enum `Option`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Next<'_, WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::TcpStream, tokio_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>>>>`
                 found enum `Option<_>`
```

Still, if I just keep the `tokio::select!` macro with just one branch then it is okay. That is, this code compiles and runs:

```rust
         tokio::select! {
             ws_msg = ws_stream.next() => {
                 match ws_msg {
                     Some(msg) => match msg {
```

My question is: is the assignment `ws_msg = ws_stream.next()` inside the `select!` doing something different than the one inside the `let`? (I mean, evidently that seems to be the case, but from the `select!` docs I just cannot infere what is the difference.
Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try matching `ws_stream.next().await`. I expect `tokio::select!()` does the awaiting, as well as actual selecting between the two futures for you under the hood. It then runs the code corresponding to the future that finished first, giving it the awaited value, which the code proceeds to match on. If you only have one stream, then you indeed don't need `select!()`, but you now need the explicit `.await`.

Comment: I am not quite familliar with tokio, but i think that select! awaits `ws_stream.next()` for you behind the scene.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I was lacking the explicit `.await` and adding it lets the code compile. Thank you both!

Comment: I've now posted it as an answer, so that the question can be marked resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match on `ws_stream.next().await`.

I expect `tokio::select!()` does the awaiting, as well as actual selecting between the two futures, for you under the hood. It then runs the code corresponding to the future that finished first, giving it the value obtained by await, and it is the awaited value that the original code matches on. If you only have one stream, then you don't need `select!()`, but you now need the explicit `.await`.